# Can't install XPad on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, command

I've download the `xpad-5.0.0.tar.bz2` from [here](https://launchpad.net/xpad).

And I follow the README in it which tells me to run `./configure` first then run `make` and `make install`, but here is the issue I'm facing.

When I run `./configure` or `'./configure'` it all said `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`.

After running `./autogen.sh` and `./configure` and also commenting `AC_PROG_INTLTOOL([0.31], [no-xml])` I get the following error:

```
[andrew@localhost xpad-5.0.0]$ vi configure.ac
[andrew@localhost xpad-5.0.0]$ ./autogen.sh
+ autoreconf --force --install
configure.ac:57: warning: macro 'AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library
configure.ac:57: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
[andrew@localhost xpad-5.0.0]$
```

Comment: What did you do before ./configure? Unarchive and change directory?

Comment: @KevinLemaire I've run this `tar -xf xpad-5.0.0.tar.bz2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL7, CentOS 7 : `xpad-5.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qj8ddLtVl9YWndwaYiZdaC-E9hLekZ8w/view?usp=sharing

Download and install: `# cd Downloads/ && yum install ./xpad-5.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

Xpad : Easy to build from the Fedora source package xpad-5.0.0-1.fc26.src.rpm http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/26/SRPMS/Packages/x/xpad-5.0.0-1.fc26.src.rpm → `$ rpmbuild -bb xpad.spec`

Answer (score 0):

The default procedure when installing from source is:

- extract the archive (in this case: `xpad-5.0.0.tar.bz2`)
- then change the directory to the extracted folder: `cd /path/to/the/extracted/folder`
- `./configure`: it will check depedancies and create `make` file
- `make` command will then just compile
- `make install` will proceed with the installation

In your case, if you can't find the `configure` file to run it. You aren't probably running this command from the right directory. Check step 2.
Also, I've just tested it with the same installer: you have to run `./autogen.sh` first to get the configure file.

> From README:      Note for developers: if you got the source code
>   straight from
>                             launchpad by using bazaar, you have to run
>                             "./autogen.sh", which will give you all files 
>                             to start "./configure"

---

**EDIT**
If you have the following error: `configure.ac:16: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_INTLTOOL`
You can comment this line in the file `configure.ac`

```
AC_PROG_INTLTOOL([0.31], [no-xml])
```

And then redo the ./autogen.sh ...

Comment: Still can't, I'm sure I'm in the directory it extract, see the screenshot [here](https://files.munucial.com/can't%20install%20xpad.png)

Comment: Check the infos I've added from README

Comment: Oh, I haven't notice that part, but after running those commands, both commands come out with error (but I get the ./configure) ([screenshot](https://files.munucial.com/Screenshot%20from%202018-01-25%2021-07-22.png))

Comment: Try to add code via edit instead of linking screenshot.

Comment: Ok, I've update the log to the question

Comment: Can you try the last edit?

Comment: After commenting I get the error `warning: macro 'AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT' not found in library`, I've found GitHub issue for this but it looks like the solution is for Debian instead of CentOS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72219/discussion-between-kevin-lemaire-and-munucial).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting the latest trunk from https://launchpad.net/xpad/+milestone/5.4.0, I had to do:

- `sudo apt install build-essential` to get a proper C compiler on $PATH
- `sudo apt install intltool` to get rid of `AC_PROG_INTLTOOL([0.31], [no-xml])` error
- `aclocal`, `autoheader`, `automake --add-missing`, `autoconf` to get `configure` file
- `./configure`, `make`, `make install`.
- then I see some GTK3 error raised by PKG check, may have to install `gtk3.0`. Too many packages to install and I don't want to break anything, so I stopped here.